# Finding your location when using Internet in android

Tags: android, mobile, location, triangulation

I have implemented location identification using GPS in android in my application but now if GPS is not available or disabed then how to identify location when internet is enabled in device. Whether using google API or triangulation or some thing else. Thank You.

Comment: how u get location without internet only use of gps..

Answer (score 1):

Have you read over this official documentation yet?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: Yes. I have gone through it already. But using NETWORK as Provider it just does not work. May be I need to send my cid and lac to Google API but how to send these to get lat long of mine in response. THank you

Comment: @rai Using NETWORK as Provider means that it will use your mobile network information. It is not internet.

Answer (score 1):

[Android will do it automatically.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

Comment: Could you please explain how. Because I have used Network_Provider but  it does not identify by its own. Also if android will do it automaticaly then why GPS used to be in android phones

Comment: `then why GPS used to be in android phones` what?

Comment: I hav done my job using GPS but when it is disabled then how to find location. Thank you

Comment: Internet connection is required to get location of nearby cell tower. Is it enabled?